# Using handler/runnable to delay the resubmission of a method

Tags: java, android, handler, runnable, postdelayed

I want to run the getVehicles() method every 10 seconds, I have the following code:

```
Handler vehiclehandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable vehiclerunnable = new Runnable() {   
        public void run() {
            getVehicles(null);
            vehiclehandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        } 
    };
```

Yet at the moment it does nothing, I've searched around and can't figure it out.

I'm new to android and have never used a handler before, only a runnable to tell something to 'runOnUiThread'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you run

```
vehiclehandler.post(vehiclerunnable)
```

at least once?

I mean outside the Runnable

Comment: It will not let me run this and I don't know why. I tried to run vehiclehandler.post(vehiclerunnable, 1000); and it would not allow it.

Comment: What does "not allow" means? does it give you a Compile time error? where did you put the post(Runnable) call?

Comment: Forgive me, it seems it has allowed it now, it was inside the onCreate method of the activity and I think it was purely Eclipse that wasn't behaving correctly, it is now working! Thanks!

Comment: If it does work for you, set the answer as accept in order to help other people recognize a  fix to similar issue. You are welcome

Comment: Yep, I have done, it wouldn't let me before as you'd answered me too fast!!

Answer (score 0):

```
final Handler lHandler = new Handler();
Runnable lRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff
        lHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};
lHandler.post(lRunnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an adjustment to your code that will make it run properly

```
Handler vehiclehandler = new Handler();
    vehiclehandler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                    getVehicles(null);
            }
        },10000);
```

But this will just delay your code before get executed. If you want to repeat the process over and over again you have to use Timer, something like:

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer();  
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 0, 10000);
private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            getVehicles(null);
        }
    }
```